# conexion ssh utilizando el servidor cpanel

Tags: ssh, cpanel

tengo una cuenta el servidor cpanel, me gustaría realizar una conexion ssh desde mi computador local al servidor remoto de mi cuenta, estoy usando ubuntu 16.04, sin embargo no he podido realizar la conexión. Cuando me logeo a mi cuenta cpanel voy a:

> Seguridad -> acceso ssh -> administrar claves ssh -> importar clave

importo las claves generada desde mi máquina local en el directorio

> ~/.ssh

con el comando

> ssh-keygen

donde se crean en el directorio anterior una clave privada y publica correspondientes a los archivos

> id_rsa

y

> id_rsa.pub

volviendo a cpanel ssh, importo las constraseñas donde se pide la clave publica y la privada respectivamente, luego las autorizo e intento entrar por ssh mediante de forma desde la linea de comando

```
ssh -vvv usernameservercpanel@ipservidorcpanel
```

pero obtengo el siguiente mensaje desde la terminal

```
penSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "<ipserver>" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <ipserver> [<ipserver>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/<userlocalmachine>/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<userlocalmachine>/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<userlocalmachine>/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<userlocalmachine>/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<userlocalmachine>/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<userlocalmachine>/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<userlocalmachine>/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/<userlocalmachine>/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Me falta un archivos desde mi máquina local, si no es con el comando `ssh-keygen`

Comment: ¿Podrías usar `ssh -vvv usernameservercpanel@ipservidorcpanel`? Con más nivel de depuración podrás saber cuándo decide el otro extremo cerrar la conexión y probablemente también el motivo.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Acabo de editar la publicación añadiendo el comando que mencionaste

Comment: ¿La máquina desde la que te conectas es también una Ubuntu ("Local version string")? En teoría sólo necesitas compartir la clave pública con cpanel para conectarte (de hecho, nunca debería salir de tu equipo la privada). Si lo has hecho deberías generar una nueva. Es probable que ese "importar clave" sea para configurar el remoto. Voy a revisar algún manual de cpanel (no lo he usado nunca) para comprobar la forma de autorizar con la clave pública.

Comment: Sí la máquina es ubuntu, mmm no sabía aquello de la máquina, aquí dejo una imagen de la interfaz donde se importan las  [claves](https://imgur.com/a/AbLwP97)